# Password recovery DriveLock, convert certificate

Tags: linux, windows, encryption, certificate, openssl

I am trying to recover a lost password of an encrypted filesystem. Software used is CenterTools DriveLock, some old version, proprietary, no documentation. Similar to VeraCrypt works with encrypted disk within multiple large files and an executable. Strings of executable mention AES/3DES/Blowfish/Twofish/CAST5/SHA-1/RIPEMD/PMC/Serpent/Whirlpool. So probably AES

Running binwalk on first encrypted file gave a private key:

```
1164 0x48C Private key in DER format (PKCS header length: 4, sequence length: 329
```

[Raw file](https://gofile.io/?c=2gtH9S) (Base64-encoded):

```
MIIBSQIBADGB5jCB4wIBADBMMDgxNjA0BgNVBAMTLURyaXZlTG9jayBDb250YWluZXItYmFzZWQg
RW5jcnlwdGlvbiBSZWNvdmVyeQIQJ4WOaLFnRpJI18AOLBgV8jANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASBgIXT
KLIzEFfYpfnouNEZndIGVWZRsumstx2RxBSUxwFei9deaeljlb9rhxBL07AQsmSK1+bjmq5XSOR+
SDBx1YFUdYYX08xQl5prQbEClHrrEgvOMlJDrHLuDwErkymHuIzMyBNX0yhbndeW0HepC+swtcCI
bTM9hLAugEkApONLMFsGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAMBggqhkiG9w0DBAUAgEAjCk9WujyWarnk2c3/8U1u
Euq6yIlEVN/c2NwIGYBNLTBC+mrsw7wX465zvXi4cpLsWTbpR8Sg5Vino3wUlUhe
```

openssl asn1parse -inform DER -in der_private_key

```
    0:d=0  hl=4 l= 329 cons: SEQUENCE          
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
    7:d=1  hl=3 l= 230 cons: SET               
   10:d=2  hl=3 l= 227 cons: SEQUENCE          
   13:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :00
   16:d=3  hl=2 l=  76 cons: SEQUENCE          
   18:d=4  hl=2 l=  56 cons: SEQUENCE          
   20:d=5  hl=2 l=  54 cons: SET               
   22:d=6  hl=2 l=  52 cons: SEQUENCE          
   24:d=7  hl=2 l=   3 prim: OBJECT            :commonName
   29:d=7  hl=2 l=  45 prim: PRINTABLESTRING   :DriveLock Container-based Encryption Recovery
   76:d=4  hl=2 l=  16 prim: INTEGER           :27858E68B167469248D7C00E2C1815F2
   94:d=3  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
   96:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
  107:d=4  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  109:d=3  hl=3 l= 128 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:85D328B2331057D8A5F9E8B8D1199DD206556651B2E9ACB71D91C41494C7015E8BD75E69E96395BF6B87104BD3B010B2648AD7E6E39AAE5748E47E483071D58154758617D3CC50979A6B41B102947AEB120BCE325243AC72EE0F012B932987B88CCCC81357D3285B9DD796D077A90BEB30B5C0886D333D84B02E804900A4E34B
  240:d=1  hl=2 l=  91 cons: SEQUENCE          
  242:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
  253:d=2  hl=2 l=  12 cons: SEQUENCE          
  255:d=3  hl=2 l=   8 prim: OBJECT            :rc4
  265:d=3  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
  267:d=2  hl=2 l=  64 prim: cont [ 0 ]
```

probably certificate for the encryption?

How can I can convert it for use in a wordlist attack with crackpkcs12 or similar?

Answer (score 0):

This file looks like PKCS#7 (CMS, S/MIME) EnvelopedData. It doesn't have the certificate's private key; it has some data (likely the file's symmetric key) *encrypted with* the certificate (basically it's similar to a PGP-encrypted file).

(I think binwalk confused it with a PKCS#8 encrypted private key, as they're both ASN.1 DER files, but the actual contents do not look like PKCS#8 at all.)

Passwords are not involved in the encryption of this file, therefore no wordlists. Those would only help if you found the actual private key that matches this "DriveLock Container-based Encryption Recovery" certificate.